# Are there any pre-built code-oss binary package available?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need the open-source build of VSCode 'code-oss' and I do not want to compile it - just want a deb package. Is it available anywhere?

I am not looking for VSCodium.

Comment: Perhaps outside the scope of the question, but why not VSCodium? It meets the requirements of the request 

Comment: I don't like the icon :D - If you ask me again, I'll make up some other reason :D

Comment: Kali Linux has a `.deb` file for it. You could try downloading that `.deb` and doing `sudo apt install ./code-oss_1.56.1-0kali3_amd64.deb`. [Here](https://http.kali.org/pool/main/c/code-oss/) are the files. You probobly want the AMD 64 deb file, but if you have ARM64, then use that one instead. Disclaimer: do not add the Kali package repos to Ubuntu. You almost certainly will mess stuff up. Kali is not a beginner OS, and is highly specialized. I do not support using Kali here. I'm saying you could try the `.deb` file from Kali, _not that you should use Kali_.